# Error in rendering custom component in DxGrid component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, dxgrid

In a blazor project I'm using the following DevExpress Blazor component:

```
<DxTextBox BindValueMode="BindValueMode.OnInput" TextChanged="(string val) => InputChanged(val)" />
```

When I'm using this component inside the  of a **DxGrid** object, I've the following error:

crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.TextBoxModel requires a value for the 'TextExpression' property. It is specified automatically when you use two-way binding('bind-Text').

In the following ticket I've read that the issue could be the missing @bind-Text:

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t834633/textbox-for-blazor-the-unable-to-set-property-textchanged-on-object-of-type-devexpress

but in my case I'm using **TextChanged** that already uses the @bind-Text attribute.

Comment: Have you already tried adding the TextExpression property? docs here: https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxTextBox.TextExpression#remarks

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below way for `DxTextBox` component to include two-way binding with the `@bind-Text` directive while still handling the `TextChanged` event:

```
@code {
    private string myText; 

    private void InputChanged(string val)
    {
        // Handle the input change event if necessary
    }
}

<DxTextBox @bind-Text="myText" BindValueMode="BindValueMode.OnInput" TextChanged="InputChanged" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
<DxTextBox @bind-Text="@MyField" @oninput="OnInputHandler" BindValueMode="BindValueMode.OnInput" >
```